# Configurar un pattern para aceptar solo 2 tipos de longitudes

Tags: html, html5, regex, entrada

Saludos poseo un input y por medio de un `pattern="[0-9]{8,11}"` intento hacer que solo acepte numeros de minimo una longitud de 8 digitos y maximo una longitud de 11 digitos pero me gustaria saber si es posible configurarlo para que acepte una longitud de 8 o de 11 es decir que no acepte longitudes de 9 o 10 digitos.

**Estoy intentando algo como esto:**

```
((?:[0-9]{8})?|(\d[0-9]{0,3}){3})
```

Pero sin resultados, solo valida los primeros 8 digitos pero no logro hacer que se validen los ultimos 3 digitos para sumar los 11 digitos, es decir que valide solo 8 u 11 digitos nada mas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera `<input type="number" name="num" required pattern="[0-9]|.{8}|.{11}">`

Me dices si te funciono... Saludos...

Comment: En principio si funciona pero acepta tambien letras, y si cambio en mi input de text a number entonces deja de aplicar el pattern y acepta asi coloque 1 solo digito, si dejo el type text funciona pero tambien acepta letras y solo necesito que escriban numero no letras `<input title = "'.$text_num_min.'"  type="text" pattern=".{8}|.{11}" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="nro" aria-describedby="nro" placeholder="'.$ph.'" name="nro" value="';
//echo $nro;
echo '" required>` Alguna otra sugerencia..?

Comment: Valida asi cómo restructure la respuesta, de favor.

Comment: Negativo asi como esta acepta solo numeros pero si coloco 1, 2 o 3 digitos los acepta..!

Comment: He colocado algo que estaba intentando pero sin exito `((?:[0-9]{8})?|(\d[0-9]{0,3}){3})`

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
\d{8}\d{3}\b|\b\d{8}\b
```

Luego de leer un poco el manual de la web https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

He solucionado usando resultados alternativos, el orden es importante ya que el algoritmo intentará coincidir primero con la alternativa de la izquierda mis primeros 8 digitos y luego si son agregados 1 o 2 numeros adicionales daria un error de validacion al igual si agrego mas de 3 numeros adicionales y solo daria valido si agrego 8 u 11 digitos.